# Stored procedure check/compare value of a column

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

VS code

```
try
{
    DBContext cl = new DBContext();
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(DBContext.ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UERMEMR..ys_Update_Borrow", cn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("BORROWING_ID", txtbox_borrow_ID.Text);

    cn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Closed Successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    txtbox_borrow_ID.Clear();
    {
        DLPatients p1 = new DLPatients();
        dt = p1.GetRecord();
        this.Grid_borrow2.SetDataBinding(dt, "", true);
    }
}
catch (Exception userEx)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error : " + userEx.Message);
}
```

SP code(I will alter)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ys_Update_Borrow]
(@BORROWING_ID int,
@STATUS varchar (50) = 'Closed',
@DATE_CLOSED datetime = null)

AS
UPDATE MEDREC_BORROWING
SET STATUS = @STATUS,
    DATE_CLOSED = COALESCE(@DATE_CLOSED , GETDATE())
FROM MEDREC_BORROWING
WHERE BORROWING_ID = @BORROWING_ID
GO
```

I want to check first if the status is closed and output a message or error to VS. and if is not closed proceed to my SP.

Please help.

Comment: Code after this line will not compile: `txtbox_borrow_ID.Clear();` Please fix that. Also what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I want to put a trap/condition to my SP, because when I clicked the button the date also changes. So i need to check first if the status column is already closed or not to prevent the date_closed from changing.

Comment: the code after the txtbox is a refresh for the data, becuase .Refresh is not working for c1TrueDBGrid

Comment: What do  you mean status column is already closed? Columns do not close, the connection is being closed.

Comment: if  Status = @STAtus  (check part where status = closed, if closed remain and date_closed should not be affected, else proceed to update below)
 FROM MEDREC_BORROWING
WHERE BORROWING_ID = @@BORROWING_ID

 ELSE

UPDATE MEDREC_BORROWING
SET STATUS = @@STATUS,
 DATE_CLOSED = COALESCE(@@DATE_CLOSED , GETDATE())
FROM MEDREC_BORROWING
WHERE BORROWING_ID = @@BORROWING_ID
GO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to check first if the status is closed

Ok so you want to check if the `Status = 'Closed'` and simply inform the user (or show error) but if it is not closed, you want to close it using your stored procedure. Your stored procedure code is already there.

Here is how to check first:

```
var command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.Parameters.Add("BORROWING_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtbox_borrow_ID.Text;
command.CommandText = "SELECT STATUS FROM MEDREC_BORROWING WHERE BORROWING_ID = @BORROWING_ID ";
string status  = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
if (status == "Closed")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already closed!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    // put your stored procedure code here and call it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it is possible to be in a 1 query/stored procedure? Just to minimize lines of coding.